# Angular.js: Set CSS when Input is on Focus

Tags: angularjs

Does someone knows how to get the following working:

If an user clicks inside "name" - Set CSS Class to XYZ on DIV ?

```
<div ng-class="???">Enter your Name here</div>

<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" required id="name"/>
```

Version: AngularJS v1.0.8

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're using Angular 1.2.x, see [`ng-focus`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngFocus) and [`ng-blur`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBlur):

```
<div ng-class="{xyz: focused}">Enter your name here</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-init="focused = false" ng-focus="focused = true" ng-blur="focused = false" id="name" required>
```

If you're using a 1.0.x version, nothing is stopping you from defining your own `focus` and `blur` directives based on [Angular 1.2.x's](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/b891c708cf1a19dc0744649547d6499f9d217e01/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L38):

```
/*
 * A directive that allows creation of custom onclick handlers that are defined as angular
 * expressions and are compiled and executed within the current scope.
 *
 * Events that are handled via these handler are always configured not to propagate further.
 */
var ngEventDirectives = {};
forEach(
  'click dblclick mousedown mouseup mouseover mouseout mousemove mouseenter mouseleave keydown keyup keypress submit focus blur copy cut paste'.split(' '),
  function(name) {
    var directiveName = directiveNormalize('ng-' + name);
    ngEventDirectives[directiveName] = ['$parse', function($parse) {
      return function(scope, element, attr) {
        var fn = $parse(attr[directiveName]);
        element.on(lowercase(name), function(event) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            fn(scope, {$event:event});
          });
        });
      };
    }];
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. I've updated my answer to include potential solutions for both stable and unstable versions.

Comment: @ArneRie You can adapt the code I pasted (which is copied from angular's source) to suit your needs. If you want to use it as-is, then you'll also need to include the [`directiveNormalize()`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/7a586e5c19f3d1ecc3fefef084ce992072ee7f60/src/ng/compile.js#L1431) function (and any functions it uses).

Comment: ng-init="focused = false" may not be necessary.  the "focused" variable should already equal false when html is loaded

Answer (score 7):

Just use this directive:

```
app.directive('ngFocusClass', function () {
  return ({
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.focus(function () {
                element.addClass('focus');
            });
            element.blur(function () {
                element.removeClass('focus');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Same as @Jigar, had to use ``on`` event for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Working example for pre-1.2.xxx versions: http://jsfiddle.net/atXAC/

In this example, the ng-customblur directive will fire a function() in your controller.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-class="{'active':hasFocus==true,'inactive':hasFocus==false}">Enter your Name here</div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-click="hasFocus=true" ng-customblur="onBlur()" required id="name"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
myApp.directive('ngCustomblur', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    var fn = $parse(attr['ngCustomblur']);      
    element.bind('blur', function(event) {        
      scope.$apply(function() {
        fn(scope, {$event:event});
      });
    });
  }
}]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.onBlur = function(){        
        $scope.hasFocus = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice but there a lot of divs and inputs, think there must be an other way (-: