# Change text color on click to have color like background

Tags: css

When the  background is red, onclick of grid cell I would like the background to turn grey but the text to remain red, yellow, green etc. How do I do that?

```css
@mixin hoverable-row($bg-color, $highlight-color: $gray-c5, $hover-color: null) {
  &:not(.p-highlight) {
    background-color: $bg-color;
    &:hover {
      @if ($hover-color) {
        background-color: $hover-color;
      }
      @else {
        background-color: rgba($bg-color, 0.6);
      }
    }
  }
}

tr.p-element.p-selectable-row {
  &.row-bg-default {
    @include hoverable-row($default-background, $hover-color: $default-highlight);
  }
  &.row-bg-red {
    @include hoverable-row($red-background);
  }
  &.row-bg-green {
    @include hoverable-row($green-background);
    color: inherit;
  }
  &.row-bg-yellow {
    @include hoverable-row($yellow-background);
    color: inherit;
  }
}
```

Comment: please add executable code in a snippet.

Comment: You will need JavaScript if you want these style changes to persist after releasing a click event

Comment: This is SCSS code which get's compiled to CSS. With CSS you can't do any of your requirements. Please add relevant code and specify what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's possible but you'll have to do some CSS magic. I haven't seen any of your HTML build up, but I suggest looking into the `:focus` and the `:focus-within` CSS suffixes.

`:focus` is a pseudo-class that is added once the user has i.e. clicked on an element. The problem here, is that this pseudo-class is originally exclusively available to form-elements. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

`:focus-within` on the other hand, is a pseudo-class added to any element *containing* a focused element. And thus can be used in conjunction with any parent element. More info can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Furthermore, a workaround to be able to set focus to any element is the `tabindex` attribute which you can add to basically any element. `tabindex` will notify the browser that, whenever a user presses 'Tab' on the keyboard, the focus of the page will be set to whatever that element is, e.g. `<tr>`. But, whenever an element *can* be focused on by `tabindex`, the browser will allow the element to be *clicked* and focused as well.

So if we combine this knowledge, you should be able to achieve what you're trying to manifest by adding `tabindex` as an attribute to your `<tr>` and/or `<td>` and extending your `tr.p-element.p-selectable-row` as such:

```
tr.p-element.p-selectable-row {
  &.row-bg-default {
    @include hoverable-row($default-background, $hover-color: $default-highlight);
  }
  &.row-bg-red {
    @include hoverable-row($red-background);
  }
  &.row-bg-green {
    @include hoverable-row($green-background);
    color: inherit;
  }
  &.row-bg-yellow {
    @include hoverable-row($yellow-background);
    color: inherit;
  }

  // add this:
  &:focus, &:focus-within{
    background:grey;
  }
}
```

I've found a similar question which received a similar response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50492334/11787139